# App.vue configration not working when error.vue page render nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

In my **Nuxt.js 3** application, I have some **configurations** in the **App.vue** component, such as direction and language. However, when an error occurs and the **error.vue** page is rendered, the configurations from App.vue do not seem to work. How can I fix this issue and ensure that the configurations remain consistent and functional even when the error page is displayed in Nuxt 3?

fix this issue and ensure that the configurations remain consistent and functional even when the error page is displayed in Nuxt 3

Comment: Could you please share some code for better understanding